# I have a problem with switching between OS (Raspbian and OSMC)

Tags: boot

I just installed OSMC on my Raspberry Pi 3. I browsed through it and now I want to go back to Raspbian. When I reboot, it it doesn't ask me to switch OS it just launches OSMC. What should I do?

Comment: How did you install OSMC? By writing the `.img` file to the SD card, I suppose. Is that right?

Answer (score 3):

If you done so by using the NOOBS image, you could do this by holding shift down during boot. As found on:

> Once you’ve installed an operating system, your Pi will boot as normal. However, NOOBS stays resident on your card, so by holding shift down during boot you can return to the recovery interface. This allows you to switch to a different operating system, or overwrite a corrupted card with a fresh install of the current one

Source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-noobs/

Otherwise you could just download the image of Raspbian and install it on your SD card.

Comment: I tried pressing SHIFT after booting but it still doesn't launch NOOBS to let me switch Operating systems

Comment: But you did use NOOBS to install OSMC? By the way, it tells you to hold shift down during boot, not just after booting. You can do a clean install anytime by directly downloading the Raspbian image and following the [install guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md). That's something that'll definitely work.